# Self Signed Certificates in Earthly

Tags: ssl, cacerts, earthly

I wanted to use earthly on corporate network that uses SSL probing that issues self-signed certificates.
I have custom ca-cert pem file, which I have been using successfully with other tools and toolchains like python, curl, etc.

I am not able to configure it with earthly though. [Documentation](https://docs.earthly.dev/docs/guides/configuring-registries/self-signed) says that this could be done in earthly config at `$HOME/.earthly/config.yml`, so I followed it and my config file looks like

```
global:
  buildkit_additional_args:
    - "-v"
    - "/Users/maca/.config/corporate/cert/cacerts"
```

No matter what I try, I am getting this error

```
    ongoing |
            internal | --> GIT CLONE https://github.com/earthly/hello-world.git
            internal | --> docker-image://docker.io/alpine/git:v2.30.1
            internal | [          ] resolve docker.io/alpine/git:v2.30.1 ... 0%
            internal | fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/earthly/hello-world.git/': SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
            internal | WARN: (GIT CLONE https://github.com/earthly/hello-world.git) error fetching default branch for repository https://github.com/earthly/hello-world.git: exit status 128
            internal | Completed in 121.889053ms
            internal | WARN: Canceled
            internal | Completed in 122.010694ms
            internal | [██████████] resolve docker.io/alpine/git:v2.30.1 ... 100%
Summary of timing information
Note that the times do not include the expansion of commands like BUILD, FROM, COPY (artifact).
            internal | () 243.899747ms
===============================================================
Total           243.899747ms
Total (real)    1m15.652038067s
Error stack trace:
github.com/moby/buildkit/util/stack.Enable
    github.com/moby/buildkit@v0.8.2-0.20210129065303-6b9ea0c202cf/util/stack/stack.go:77
github.com/moby/buildkit/util/grpcerrors.FromGRPC
    github.com/moby/buildkit@v0.8.2-0.20210129065303-6b9ea0c202cf/util/grpcerrors/grpcerrors.go:188
github.com/moby/buildkit/util/grpcerrors.UnaryClientInterceptor
    github.com/moby/buildkit@v0.8.2-0.20210129065303-6b9ea0c202cf/util/grpcerrors/intercept.go:41
google.golang.org/grpc.(*ClientConn).Invoke
    google.golang.org/grpc@v1.38.0/call.go:35
github.com/moby/buildkit/api/services/control.(*controlClient).Solve
    github.com/moby/buildkit@v0.8.2-0.20210129065303-6b9ea0c202cf/api/services/control/control.pb.go:1321
github.com/moby/buildkit/client.(*Client).solve.func2
    github.com/moby/buildkit@v0.8.2-0.20210129065303-6b9ea0c202cf/client/solve.go:215
golang.org/x/sync/errgroup.(*Group).Go.func1
    golang.org/x/sync@v0.0.0-20210220032951-036812b2e83c/errgroup/errgroup.go:57
runtime.goexit
    runtime/asm_amd64.s:1371
```

It seems like earthly is ignoring my cacerts file. Does anyone know how to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do more than just mount the certs directory; Buildkit does not pick them up. To specify custom certificates for a registry, The documentation you linked details how you can use a custom self-signed certificate with a singular Docker Registry, and not in this more general case across a whole build. You can use these docs if you need to push or pull from a registry with custom certificates. Do not forget the additional configuration in `buildkit_additional_config` if this needs to be configured in your situation.

Now, on to why `+hello-world` is failing. The `GIT CLONE` command uses `git` under the hood. While `git` on your local machine may be configured to use these custom certificates, the `git` inside the build here is different, and does not share the same certificate configuration. You'll need to bring in the certificates manually via a `COPY`, or using a [`--secret`](https://docs.earthly.dev/docs/earthly-command#secret-or-s-less-than-secret-id-greater-than-less-than-value-greater-than)/[`--secret-file`](https://docs.earthly.dev/docs/earthly-command#secret-file-less-than-secret-id-greater-than-less-than-path-greater-than)/[`--build-arg`](https://docs.earthly.dev/docs/earthly-command#build-arg-less-than-key-greater-than-less-than-value-greater-than) to make it accessible, depending on your use case.

We have some examples in our unit tests that cover this use case. [Here is using one with a custom clone over HTTPS using a custom cert](https://github.com/earthly/earthly/blob/main/tests/private-https/Earthfile); and [here is how we are adding a custom cert to a build](https://github.com/earthly/earthly/blob/main/tests/git-webserver/Earthfile#L58-L60).